# How to speed up dpkg-deb build

Tags: dpkg, compiling, application-development, deb, development

I use `dpkg-deb` to build a `deb` package. However, in my CI tests, `dpkg-deb` takes a lot of time to complete (~6min). Is there a way to speed up the process?

I have tried setting compression to none:

```
dpkg-deb -Znone -z0 -b debianPackageDirPath
```

This is the original code that I use (it is in JavaScript but calls `dpkg-deb` through `fakeroot`):

```javascript
  const compressionLevel = process.env.IS_RELEASE_BRANCH ? 6 : 0;
  const compressionType = process.env.IS_RELEASE_BRANCH ? 'xz' : 'none';
  spawnSync(
    'fakeroot',
    ['dpkg-deb', `-Z${compressionType}`, `-z${compressionLevel}`, '-b', debianPackageDirPath],
    {
      stdio: 'inherit'
    }
```

Here is the documentation for `dpkg-deb` just in case: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg/dpkg-deb.1.en.html

In case you wonder what software this is, see the link to [this Azure pipeline job](https://dev.azure.com/atomcommunity/atomcommunity/_build/results?buildId=875&view=logs&j=0da5d1d9-276d-5173-c4c4-9d4d4ed14fdb&t=cccdf131-0893-5d7b-ccea-9ccfc8953f95&l=5023).

Edit: I could bring it to 4min by using `sudo` instead of `fakeroot`, but it still seems long.